# What does "an A/B metaphor" mean?

Tags: meaning, mathematics, logic

I wonder what "an A/B metaphor" means, for example, in the following quote from Wikipedia about [formal language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language):

> "In some applications, especially in logic, the alphabet is also known as the vocabulary and words are known as formulas or sentences; this breaks **the letter/word metaphor** and replaces it by **a word/sentence metaphor**."

In the example, what is used as a metaphor of what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In propositional calculus especially, there is a very small number of symbols available, and a very small number of ways they can combine. So it's tempting to think of this small stock of mostly special characters ***( ¬ ⋀ ⋁ ⊃ ≡ p q r s )*** as an **alphabet**.

In fact, however, these letters don't represent parts of words -- rather, they **are** words, and thus represent parts of sentences. For instance, **¬** means *not*, **⋀** means *and*, and actual alphabetic letters like **p, q, r, s** are used to represent any proposition (i.e, sentence) at all. In other words, logic represents **Sentences**, and therefore its parts represent **Words**. That's the **Word/Sentence metaphor**.

If, however, one refers to the stock of symbols as an *alphabet*, then they are **Letters** and thus they make up **Words**, not sentences. This is the **Letter/Word metaphor**. They're not incompatible, but they do require one to switch assumptions, and to treat [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf) as [mathematics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-MathematicalNotation.pdf) (which uses formulae and letters) instead of semantics (which uses words and sentences).

For details, see my [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! In your next to last sentence, does "formulae" mean "words"?

Comment: No. It's just the Latin plural for _formula_. More formal, you know.

Answer (score 3):

There's the general question about 'A/B' and then there's the instance about formal languages. First the content:

Mathematical terminology is sometimes metaphorical. In the study of formal languages (not within a formal language), a 'language' is a 'set' of 'sequences' of 'elements'.

One mapping to more understandable things, that is a metaphor, is that a sequence corresponds to word, and element corresponds to an alphabet character, and the language is the set of acceptable words or vocabulary items, the **letter/word metaphor**.

Another metaphor is that a sequence is a sentence, the elements are the (finite set of) dictionary words. This is the **word/sentence metaphor**.

The wording of that example is unfortunate; it uses 'break' as though it's more meaningful when all that is really involved is a -different- metaphor.

As to 'A/B', It is an informal way in writing of signifying a pair. It is not a special way of giving any particular meaning to 'metaphor'. It just means **involves a pair of things**, A and B. That's all, nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

In logic the alphabet is also know as the vocabulary. A vocabulary is a collection of words that a human can use to form utterances. Utterances are typically sentences.

The components of logical formulas can be metaphorically referred to as words and sentences.